# $wpdb select all meta for each post

Tags: mysql, wpdb

I'm running the following query trying to get the data and associated meta data of a huge number of posts:

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date,
    wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key
    FROM wp_postmeta
    INNER JOIN wp_posts
    ON wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_posts.id
    WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
    LIMIT 5
```

And that returns the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Hello world!
            [post_date] => 2015-11-11 08:44:54
            [ID] => 1
            [post_id] => 1
            [meta_key] => _edit_lock
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Home
            [post_date] => 2015-11-11 08:44:54
            [ID] => 2
            [post_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => _wp_page_template
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Home
            [post_date] => 2015-11-11 08:44:54
            [ID] => 2
            [post_id] => 2
            [meta_key] => _edit_last
        )
...
```

But now I realise I need a much more complex query, as what I'd like is something like the following:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Hello world!
            [post_date] => 2015-11-11 08:44:54
            [ID] => 1
            [post_id] => 1
            [meta] => array(
                '_wp_page_template' => 'home.php',
                '_edit_last' => 2015-11-11 08:44:54,
            )
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => Home
            [post_date] => 2015-11-11 08:44:54
            [ID] => 2
            [post_id] => 2
            [meta] => array(
                '_wp_page_template' => 'home.php',
                '_edit_last' => 2015-11-11 08:44:54,
            )
        )

    [2] => stdClass Object
        (
            [post_title] => About us
            [post_date] => 2015-11-11 08:44:54
            [ID] => 3
            [post_id] => 3
            [meta] => array(
                '_wp_page_template' => 'home.php',
                '_edit_last' => 2015-11-11 08:44:54,
            )
        )
```

Comment: Don't use direct SQL queries unless you don't have an API option (or an extremely good reason), which you do have for this.

Comment: @Djave: Please clear your requirement `latitudes and longitudes?`.

Answer (score 0):

This is really simple.

```
get_post_meta($postid);
```

This will return all values in about the same syntax.

In  a more workable loop:

```
<?php
    $custom = new WP_Query(array("posts_per_page" => -1))
    if( $custom->have_posts() ) {
        while ( $custom->have_posts() ) {
            the_post();
            $data = get_post_meta(get_the_ID());
        }
    } else {
        /* No posts found */
    }
?>
```

Comment: Thanks for this – the issue is I'm getting 1,500 posts each with associated latitudes and longitudes, so I'm trying to make a custom query that will get all meta in one mysql query, not n+1 / 1,501 queries!

Comment: Ah okay. Do you accually need ALL the metainformation or just the latitudes and longitudes?

Comment: pretty much just the latitude and longitudes. I'm 90% sure I can just do an `INNER JOIN` but I can't get my head around it – thanks so much for taking the time to answer

Answer (score 0):

For anyone stumbling across this.. I resolved this by doing the following:

(adapted for your code)

```
SELECT wp_posts.post_title, wp_posts.post_date,
wp_posts.ID, wp_postmeta.post_id, wp_postmeta.meta_key, 
GROUP_CONCAT(wp_postmeta.meta_key SEPARATOR ':') AS meta_keys

FROM wp_postmeta
INNER JOIN wp_posts
ON wp_postmeta.post_id=wp_posts.id
WHERE wp_posts.post_status = 'publish'
GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id
LIMIT 5
```

By doing `GROUP_CONCAT(wp_postmeta.meta_key SEPARATOR ':') AS meta_keys` and `GROUP BY wp_postmeta.post_id` it creates a results `meta_keys` where you can then in PHP explode on `:`

```
$meta_keys = explode(':', $item->meta_keys);
```